# Probability Conditional Issue

Tags: probability, statistics

The chances of catching a cold by workers working
in an ice factory during winter are 25%. What is
the probability that out of 5 workers, 4 or more
will catch a cold?

I am getting the answer 1/1024 which is incorrect. Can someone explain me about this where I am wrong?

Here are the steps which I followed:

> With $n$ independent trials and a probability for success, $p$, then the probability that we get $x$ successes is: $$\dbinom n x p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$$
>
> So the probability that we get *at least* $x$ successes is $$\sum_{k=x}^n \dbinom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
>
> Thus for the problem, we have $n=5$, $p=0.25$, and we at least $5$ successes (even though the maximum is 5 successes, let us do this rigorously).
>
> Then we have $$\sum_{k=5}^5 \dbinom 5 k \left(\dfrac 1 4\right)^k \left(1-\dfrac 1 4\right)^{5-k}$$
>
> Which is equal to$$\dbinom 5 5 \left(\dfrac 1 4\right)^5 \left(\dfrac 3 4\right)^{0} =\dfrac{1}{1024}$$

Comment: Do you want to edit the question telling us how do you obtain $\frac1{1024}$? then someone can point out your mistake.

Comment: okay. I am editing the question

Answer (score 3):

You considered $5$ or more, that is, exactly $5$. So you've got $$\binom{5}5p^5=\frac1{1024}.$$

However the text said $4$ or $5$ illnesses. ("at least four") So you would have had to add $$\binom54p^4(1-p)=\frac{15}{1024}.$$

The final result would have been

$$\frac1{1024}+\frac{15}{1024}=\frac{16}{1024}=\frac1{64}.$$